# Jetty Websocket API Session

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, jetty

Hello I try many hours to get the Websocket API from Jetty with Sessions running.

My Problem is that, i can't interact externally with the Session, to send Data.
I can only interact to all Sessions and not only to one.

I tried to use the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" as Session Key, but it always returns **java.lang.NullPointerException** as the onWebSocketError.

***I already tried to save the Session in a HashMap but every time, when i like to execute a sendString the Session in the HashMap is NULL.***

My Code:

Connect Method

```
@Override
public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sessionIO) {
    sessionIO.setIdleTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    System.out.print(gsonIO.toJson(this.getSession().getUpgradeResponse().getHeaders()));

    sessionsIO.add(sessionIO);
    loggerIO.log(LogType.SOCKET, "New Socket Connection from Client " + sessionIO.getRemoteAddress() + " with Sesssion ID: " + sessionIO.getPolicy().getBehavior().name() + ".");
}
```

My Function where i try to fetch my Session out of the Array

```
 public static Session getSession(String handshakeIO) {
    //String handshakeIO = sessionIO.getUpgradeRequest().getHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Key");
    Session cacheIO = null;

    for (Session rowIO : sessionsIO) {
        if (handshakeIO.equalsIgnoreCase(rowIO.getUpgradeRequest().getHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Key"))) {
            loggerIO.info("FOUND SESSION WITH Sec-WebSocket-Key " + handshakeIO + ".");
            cacheIO = rowIO;
        }
    }
    return cacheIO;
}
```

Fetching Session

```
@SneakyThrows
@EventHandler
public static void onJoin(UserLoginEvent eventIO) {
    Habbo playerIO = eventIO.habbo;
    int idIO = playerIO.getHabboInfo().getId();

    for (Session rowIO : sessionsIO) {
        if (rowIO.isOpen()) {
            rowIO.getRemote().sendString(gsonIO.toJson(new ActionPaket("broadcast", "joinedplayer")));
        }
    }

    if (ViceCache.playerIO.containsKey(idIO)) {
        Session sessionIO = ViceCache.getSession(ViceCache.playerIO.get(idIO).getSessionIO());

        if (sessionIO.isOpen()) {
            sessionIO.getRemote().sendString(gsonIO.toJson(new ActionPaket("session", "granted")));
        }

        playerIO.whisper("Voicechat was successfully connected to Room.");
        loggerIO.info("Player " + playerIO.getHabboInfo().getUsername() + " in Cache joined the Server, sending Callback.");
    } else {
        playerIO.whisper("To use Voice Chat, please download the Offical Vice Client.");
        loggerIO.warning("Can't find Player " + playerIO.getHabboInfo().getUsername() + " with ID " + idIO + " in Cache, cannot send Callback for ViceChat.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you explain your goals?  what are you trying to do? (it almost seems like you are trying to make a chat server with rooms)

Comment: I have 2 external Clients one for the Game and one for a Voicechat, i like to couple boths, so that the Client can Speak if he is connected. Problem was that i can't use the Session Objects from Jetty because they got deleted after some seconds don't know why. So i wrode my own Session System.

Comment: The WebSocket Session object only gets removed once the WebSocket connection is closed.